# Selecting data-style-name in (Python/Splinter)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, splinter

I'd like to select an item in a specific color from an unordered list. One poster in another thread suggested I try `browser.find_by_xpath("/html/body/a[@data-style-name='COLOR HERE'"`, but that didn't work. The XPath (taken from the [website](http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/pants/dvgli54c3/r0ukes391)) looks like this: `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[1]`. How could click this option in Splinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try related XPath like

```
//a[@data-style-name='COLOR HERE']
```

because `/html/body/a[@data-style-name='COLOR HERE']` means that target link is immediate child of `body` node which is obviously not true...

Comment: Hmm, I keep getting the following error when I try to find or click the element: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath.'`

Comment: So try `find_by_xpath()` instead (if you use Splinter). You should use `find_element_by_xpath()` for pure Selenium, not for Splinter...